# Adding keyboard controls to slider

Tags: javascript, html

I have a lightbox slider that is used to scroll through product images, I'd like the user to be able to use the arrow keys on their keyboard to scroll through the images rather than having to click the arrows and use the ESC key to close the lightbox.

Lightbox Slider code:

```
  // T50 Lightbox
    // Open the Modal
    function openModal() {
      document.getElementById('T50Lightbox').style.display = "block";
    }

    // Close the Modal
    function closeModal() {
      document.getElementById('T50Lightbox').style.display = "none";
    }

    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("T50-Slides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
      var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
      captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
    }
```

I have the following code that closes a menu I have using the ESC key, how do I apply this to the lightbox along with the use of the arrow keys?

```
    function closeMenu() {
        $(".menu-trigger").removeClass("open");
        $(".navigation").removeClass("nav-open");
        $(".col").removeClass("c-in");
      }

    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        closeMenu();
            }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add listeners for arrow keys in the same way you did it for `esc` key. The keycode for arrow keys are:-

```
left arrow  37
up arrow    38
right arrow 39
down arrow  40
```

You can write the following code:-

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
   if (e.keycode === 27) {
     closemenu();
    }
    if(e.keycode === 37) {
      // code for showing next slide
        plusSlides(n)
      }
     // same for other keys
   }
```